# Node.js crashing when requiring JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, parsing, require

I have been trying to move some variables to an external file so I decided to create a config.json

```
{
  "username":"...",
  "password":"...",
  "identity_secret":"...",
  "shared_secret":"...",
  "hostname":"127.0.0.1",
  "owner":"..."
}
```

And then require it as a module

```
'use strict'

var ACCEPT = 0xf
var REPORT = 0xff
var DECLINE = 0xfff

var fs = require('fs')
var config = require('./config.json')
```

But whenever I run the script I constantly get this error

```
module.js:457
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'config.json'
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
  at Module.require (module.js:483:17)
  at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
  at Object.<anonymous> (/root/steam-bot/steam_bot.js:8:14)
  at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
  at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
```

I'm on `node v6.4.0` with `node bot.js`

This is a single file script so I couldn't have had the chance to change the loading directory and both files are indeed in the same directory

*It seems the import isn't throwing the error as this script works*

```
var fs = require('fs')
var config = require('./config.json')

console.log(config.username)
```

Comment: is your file which requires json is in the same directory?

Comment: You are giving a wrong path of `config.json` in `require.js`

Comment: Any hints how to reproduce your problem?

Comment: This is all to it and as this require is async nothing below should be effecting it

Comment: Please tell us more information on how to reproduce the error you get

Comment: have you maybe misspelled your filename?

Comment: @tolunlade One thing you have not provided is the command you use to run your code. Please put the *exact* command your are using.

Comment: can you show the output when you run `node -e "require('./config.json')"`in your directory?

Comment: nothing as it should, is it possible in my script something is breaking the import from it's original async flow?

Comment: Why is the error saying that you're trying to use `require('config.json')` instead of `require('./config.json')`? Those two are really different.

Comment: For some reason deleting a polldata.json stopped this error from being thrown

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons you are getting that error. 1) Your JSON file is not in the same directory with your script or 2) You are using an old version of Node.js (before 0.5). Make sure your main script and JSON file is in the same directory. Also, if you don't want to update your Node.js, you can still include JSON file like this:

```
var imported = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('.\\config.json') + '');
```

Comment: He uses v6.4.0 he mentioned it

Comment: @UnknownDeveloper I know, but I am also writting this for future users who get the same issue. Maybe my answer can help them.

Comment: Oh ok nice thinking!

Comment: Neither of these reasons are the case

Comment: This will not work if the current working directory is set elsewhere. Something like `path.join(__dirname, "./config.json")` works better

Comment: @TamasHegedus This is just an example. I assume OP has enough programming experience to know that.

Comment: @tolunlade If neither of these cases are your, you need to  provide more informations about your problem and also let us know how to reproduce your error, otherwise I cannot say anything more than this.

Answer (score 0):

I looked through the rest of the script and realized there was another polldata.json being parsed that is generated by a lib I'm using.

For some strange reason this being improper threw

```
Error: Cannot find module 'config.json'
```